# PayloadTooLargeError when uploading multiple Excel files despite increasing request size limit

Tags: reactjs, node.js, json, express

I'm encountering an issue in my Node.js application where I receive a PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large error when attempting to upload more than 2 Excel files, each with around 500 rows. Here's a simplified version of my setup:

I have an Express server with a route that handles data processing and insertion into a database. When I upload small datasets, everything works fine. However, when I attempt to upload larger datasets, I encounter the PayloadTooLargeError.

I've already tried increasing the request size limit in my Express app using the body-parser middleware with configurations such as { limit: '50mb' }, but the error persists.

Here's my simplified code structure:

'server.js'

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dataProcessingRoutes = require('./routes/dataProcessing');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

app.use(dataProcessingRoutes);

app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log("Listening...");
});
```

Route for processing and inserting data into the database:

```
const router = express.Router();
const getPool = require('../utils/db');
const sql = require('mssql');

router.post('/processData', async (req, res) => {
  // Handling data processing and insertion...
});

module.exports = router;
```

my Dash.js :

```
    let allData = [];
    let processedFilesCount = 0;
    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        const data = e.target.result;
        const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
  
        const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
        const dataJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
  
        allData = [...allData, ...dataJson]; // Concaténer les données de chaque fichier
        processedFilesCount++; // Incrémenter le compteur de fichiers traités
        console.log('Contenu de allData :', allData); // Ajoutez cette ligne pour afficher le contenu de allData
        if (processedFilesCount === acceptedFiles.length) {
            const processedData = allData.map(row => ({
            date: row.DATE,
            responseCode: row['RESPONSE CODE'],
            terminalId: row['TERMINAL ID'],
          }));
  
          setProcessedData(processedData); 
  
          // Effectuer ici la vérification et le traitement des données si nécessaire
          console.log('Données prêtes pour le traitement :', processedData);
        }
      };
  
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    });
  }, []);
  
  
  const insertIntoDatabase = () => {
    // Effectuez la logique d'insertion dans votre base de données ici
    setProcessing(true); // Indiquer que le traitement est en cours
    console.log('Données prêtes pour le traitement  :', processedData);
    // Envoyez les données au backend
    axios.post('http://localhost:8081/processData', { data: processedData })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setProcessing(false); // Indiquer que le traitement est terminé
        setInsertionSuccess(true)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi des données au backend :', error);
        setProcessing(false); // Assurez-vous que le traitement est également terminé en cas d'erreur
      });
  };
```

my console in the navigator also show the message bellow :

> Blocage d’une requête multiorigines (Cross-Origin Request) : la politique « Same Origin » ne permet pas de consulter la ressource distante située sur http://localhost:8081/processData. Raison : l’en-tête CORS « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » est manquant. Code d’état : 413.

Despite these efforts, the PayloadTooLargeError persists. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You need to translate any error messages into English.

Comment: I am removing the SQL server tag because it doesn't appear relevant to the issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

By rearranging the middleware setup, I was able to fix the PayloadTooLargeError by setting appropriate limits for request payloads, and the missing CORS header issue by configuring CORS handling before other middleware.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Reordered middleware setup to resolve issues
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(express.json());
```